# error java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0

Tags: java, sql, sqlexception

here is my code
 I wrote following java method and when I call it, gives me the error
1:) i have to update date when user enter challan number in textfield.

```
public class datechnagemainmenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "dd/MMM/YYYY ";
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
Date date = new Date();

/**
 * Creates new form datechnagemainmenu
 */
public datechnagemainmenu() {
    initComponents();

    String dt = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

    System.out.println(dt);
    jLabel4.setText(dt);
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

    jLabel7.setText("jLabel7");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Carlsberg india pvt ltd", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.TOP));

    jLabel2.setText("Phone number:42570000");

    jLabel3.setText("ver  -02/03/1.01");

    jLabel4.setText("date");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(106, 106, 106)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 124, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 36, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel4)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

    jLabel5.setText("main menu");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(159, 159, 159)
            .addComponent(jLabel5)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel5)
            .addGap(25, 25, 25))
    );

    jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

    jLabel6.setText("Please enter the bill no");

    jLabel9.setText("give <zero> to exit");

    jTextField1.setText("0");
    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel8)
                            .addGap(54, 54, 54))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel9)
                            .addContainerGap())))))
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jLabel8)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel9)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 7, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    //System.out.println(jTextField1);
    System.out.println("gfj");
    if (evt.getSource() == jTextField1) //add
    {

         try {
            String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/indospirit";
            String uName = "root";
            String uPass = "paras123";

            //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            java.sql.Driver d = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);


            String sql =("update challan set date=('dt') where challan_no='"+jTextField1+"' ");

           System.out.println(sql);
            PreparedStatement ps;
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

          ps.setString(1,jTextField1.getText().trim()); 
          ps.setString(2,jLabel4.getText().trim());
            int i = ps.executeUpdate();



        if(i>0)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record Updated");
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record NOT Updated");
            }

        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex1) {
            System.err.println(ex1.toString());
        }
}                                           

}
```

Comment: Search for `Parameter index out of range SQL exception` on google.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
  String sql =("update challan set date=('dt') where challan_no='"+jTextField1+"' ");
```

Need to look like this

```
 String sql =("update challan set date=? where challan_no=?");
```

Change the index according to ? in the query

```
ps.setString(1,jTextField1.getText().trim()); 
ps.setString(2,jLabel4.getText().trim());
```

Comment: +1 for that; not only to solve your problem, but this advice makes any java code more difficult to tamper with.  The original version was prone to suffer SQL injection

Comment: what is diffrence between prepared statement and create statement .

Answer (score 1):

This is a SQL exception. You have passed parameters to your prepared statement, but you haven't used them in your SQL String (Statement).

Comment: Thanks Jacob for rectifying my silly mistake. I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Swing error it's an SQL error. Pasting just the method with the SQL code would've made this MUCH easier to read.

Your prepared statement doesn't have any parameters so when you try to set values you get that error. Use ? for parameters. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html for details.